# Django passing string arguments

Tags: python, django, path, arguments

Please how can I pass a string arguments to django path 
`path('mysite/?$', search, name='search')`
instead of the `?$` I want to pass the argument that the get method has `!` how can I do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like that:

```
path('mysite/<int:number>', views.search, name='search'),
```

or

```
path('mysite/<str:search>', views.search, name='search'),
```

in you urls.py

Also don't forget to add an argument to the search in the views.py

Comment: One correction: this code will work only for django version > 2.0, otherwise you need to use regular expression. The simplest one (but not the best) is something like path('mysite/?.*$', views.search, name='search'),

Comment: That's correct. I am assuming that Django 2.xx is installed.

Comment: Well, then this is the best solution.